# Laravel: alter notifications table and insert custom data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm implementing the Laravel notification system. I have made a test of insertion in DB and it has gone well but when registering the notification I see that it arrives with "strange" data (from my point of view).

| id | type | notifiable_type | notifiable_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 634db0ee-a9c0... | App\Notifications\HeatMapNotification | App\Models\User | 1 |

I don't understand why "id" column comes with an id with type uuid. I mean, with an autoincremental id would be enough (I think).

In the "type" column I would like to insert a much simpler text.

I don't see any use for the column "notifiable_type". In my case the notifiable entities will always be users.

Also I would like to change some column names (notifiable_id --> user_id)

How could I make these changes?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could switch to using your own notification system that is essentially a copy of Laravel's or you could just leave it, which is what I recommend. You never know, you might want to notify something else in the future.

Comment: @kemp yes, I understand you, but I find it very annoying to see text strings like "App\Notifications\HeatMapNotification" when I really just want to know the type of entity ("heat_map"), and even others like the type of notifiable entity. When could it be something other than a user? The uuid column type also has no sense for me. I really don't understand the way they thought when they made this table.

Comment: They are trying to provide the most flexibility. Consider an application which has two types of users: doctors and patients. They both log into the system and can receive notifications. Also, what if you put your notifications in subdirectories? `App\Notifications\Appointment\Reminder` and `App\Notifications\Prescription\Reminder` would both be called reminder. So, why not just store the full class name?

Comment: @kemp, yeah, you're right. Anyway, it's not neccessary in my case so I'll just wait for help. Thanks for the tip kemp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See at the DatabaseNotification class and see some of your requirements. For example by default have

```
  /**
     * The "type" of the primary key ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
```

maybe working on this you can enable the autoincrement ID.
In DatabaseChannel class is when store some data in notifications table

```
protected function buildPayload($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $notification->id,
            'type' => get_class($notification),
            'data' => $this->getData($notifiable, $notification),
            'read_at' => null,
        ];
    }
```

I think about the type column, it's easier cast the notification type

```
if ($notification->type === HeatMapNotification::class)
```

and notifiable_type, you can manage a lot of diff User models...depend of the project you dev, so Laravel go into this.